# Prove that the quadrilateral connecting the midpoints of a rhombus is a rectangle using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Here is my attempt, consider the following picture of a rhombus:
[image]

If we think of the rhombus as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the point $E= A+\frac{1}{2}(B-A)$,  $F=B+\frac{1}{2}(C-B)$, $H=A+\frac{1}{2}(D-A)$. And we want to show that the dot product of the vectors $\overline{EF}$ and $\overline{EH}$ is $\overline{0}$. We solve for $F-E$ and $H-E$ to get $\frac{1}{2}\overline{AC}$ and $\frac{1}{2}\overline{BD}$. And the argument goes like : since the diagonals of a rhombus are perpendicular to each other, so then the dot product of $\overline{EF}$ and $\overline{EH}$ is $0$. I'm wondering how to do this last step using linear algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that 
$$(F-E)\cdot(H-E)=\left(\frac{B+C}{2}-\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{A+D}{2}-\frac{A+B}{2}\right)=\frac{(C-A)\cdot(D-B)}{4}.$$
It follows that 
$$FE\perp HE \Leftrightarrow (F-E)\cdot(H-E)=0 \Leftrightarrow  (C-A)\cdot(D-B)=0 \Leftrightarrow  CA\perp DB.$$

Comment: So we still uses the fact that CA is perpendicular to DB for a rhombus?

Comment: @mathpadawan Yes, all you need is that diagonals are perpendicular. So the property holds for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodiagonal_quadrilateral

Comment: Is there another way that doesn't uses that fact?

Comment: @mathpadawan That "fact" is equivalent to the property you want prove. You can not avoid that!